# Timer Countdown Resetting automatically

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have used a timer in my webapp and it is working fine with the functionality. 
But my problem is the timer is getting reset automatically when  it is deployed in the server. Example: If the time is set to 70 mins, At some point it like 45min - 40min time gap it is getting reset
Here is the code which I have used for this.

```
if (Convert.ToInt32(Session["minute"]) == 0 && Convert.ToInt32(Session["seconds"]) == 0)
{
    // Your code 
}
else
{
    if (Convert.ToInt32(Session["seconds"]) < 1)
    {
        Session["seconds"] = 59;
        if (Convert.ToInt32(Session["minute"]) != 0)
            Session["minute"] = Convert.ToInt32(Session["minute"]) - 1;
    }
    else
        Session["seconds"] = Convert.ToInt32(Session["seconds"]) - 1;
    string mins = "", sec = "";
    if (Convert.ToInt32(Session["minute"]) <= 9)
        mins = "0" + Session["minute"].ToString();
    else
        mins = Session["minute"].ToString();
    if (Convert.ToInt32(Session["seconds"]) <= 9)
        sec = "0" + Session["seconds"].ToString();
    else
        sec = Session["seconds"].ToString();
    lblTimer.Text = "Time Left : " + mins + " : " + sec;
}
```

Comment: if (Convert.ToInt32(Session["minute"]) != 0) should be if (Convert.ToInt32(Session["minute"]) > 0)

Comment: The method is working fine for me. There is no issues with it.

Comment: but the logic is flawed. if minutes are less than 0 your condition will be true, which it should not be. So you should check for greater than zero.

Comment: Fine. Thanks for the help. I will look into it. But What about my main issue. Any Solution ?

Comment: it can't be answered, unless you provide the code that shows the initial settings of Session variables.

Comment: Session["minute"] = 30; Session["seconds"]=0; It is done it page load event under !IsPostBack.

Comment: and there isn't any other place in your code that is setting this variable?

Comment: no... It is done only in pageload.

Comment: what is the session timeout set to?

Comment: your code seems fine to me. Debugging is the only option.

Comment: At present I have done in Session. Is this same method can be implemented in ViewState ? Dose any changes do be done if i do in ViewState ?

Comment: How do you use this code? Since it seem to be decreasing the time by one second each time it is called, does that mean that you are calling it once every second (for example using AJAX)? Why not make the counter in pure javascript and only "sync" it on postback. To keep track of the elapsed time on the server you could store for instance a UTC timestamp in the session...

Comment: I have script manager and a update panel. Outside update panel I have placed timer control and inside update panel content template the label which displays the Time left and in Triggers AsyncPostBackTrigger I have given the Control id and event name of the timer.